# generate random names in SAS

Tags: sas

```
Data Have
   Hill
   Bush
   Hill
   Bush
   George
   Chase

Data Want

   Billy
   Andrew
   Billy
   Andrew
   John
   Doe
```

These are just sample "Want" data so names generated by your code will be totally different but must follow a logic where by every occurrence of "Hill" gets replaced by unique random name (Billy). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Find a list of names (either make it, or download some - list of Harry Potter characters, list of common first names/baby names, list of common last names, etc.)
2. Produce a dataset like so:

Format dataset:

```
Start = ID or other way to identify the real person (first/last name combo)
Label = First Name + Last Name selected from list (or do this 2x, one for each)
Fmtname = RANDONNAMEF
```

Then read it in as a format with `PROC FORMAT CNTLIN=` and apply it to the dataset.